# Photos received through Hangouts

Tags: google-hangouts

I can access the photographs that I sent through a Hangouts album but what about the photos received from my friend through Hangouts?

Where will these photos be stored?

Is it not possible to access these photos (received) other than downloading them?

Comment: I closed this questions because Hangouts was retired.

Answer (score 0):

From [Hangouts Help](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3115410?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en):

> Your photos will be added to a shared album on Google+ that's visible to you and the other people in the Hangout. If you don't have Google+, you can view the photos in a Google Album Archive.
>
> Photos sent when the Hangout history is turned off will be temporarily visible in the shared album. After a short time, they'll be deleted from the album.

Comment: Even the above comes from the official documentation, it's "obsolete". See https://support.google.com/plus/answer/6262471?hl=en